# Browserify require stream with expose

Tags: browserify

I have a problem with requiring programmatically created modules for browserify.

```
var File = require("vinyl"),
    browserify = require("browserify");

bundler = browserify();
bundler.require(new File({contents: new Buffer(...)}), {expose: "mymodule"});

bundler.bundle();
...
```

In the output file i have the content of buffer, but not exposed to "mymodule".

Does anybody used this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in browserify, but was fixed with this patch: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/907

and your above code should work in version 6.0.1 and above

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted James Halliday (substack, creator of browserify) has been hard at work coming up with the browserify handbook: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook

This resource is excellent. It goes really deep into how requires work and resolve dependencies in general. It is by far the best resource I have ever seen on the subject. Perhaps if you (or anyone else landing on this question with a similar problem) give it a read, the answer might jump out at you.

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but I only recently found this resource, and I wish I knew it existed earlier.

For an introduction to browserify, I recommend watching this tagtree video: http://tagtree.tv/browserify-an-intro?share_code=uncoopered-inspirer﻿